# In App purchase in iOS Apps using PayTm - WebPage

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, paytm, in-app-subscription

I need a clarification on how to use **IOS** **In App purchase** for **subscribing** a service within the app(eg: a 3 month **subscription** to access features in a Matrimony app ). Can I use **PayTm** **transaction** as **In App** which directs to a **PayTm web page**. Or else how to get such a functionality **payment option**.Please guide me as I'm new in this module

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For content that is delivered in the app (which it sounds like yours is) you must use Apple's In-App purchase.  You cannot use an external payment mechanism.

Comment: which means I can't use PayTm transaction??

Comment: That is correct.  See https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase

Comment: To use third party transaction you can transfer user to safari or safariviewcontroller

Comment: You can try that, but your app will be rejected once Apple sees you doing it.

Answer (score -2):

Below links will help to resolve your query.

```
https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/3b361da0f038 : `using Paytm`
https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/
https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/3b361da0f038
```

Hope it will help you...!!!